# If $X$ is a proper scheme over $k$, is $X/G$ separated?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ a proper scheme over a field $k$ and let $G$ a finite group of its automorphism (as $k$-scheme).

Let suppose that the quotient $X/G$ exists, is it is separated? How to prove it?

If the general case is false, is true with additional ipotesis? For example  is true if $X$ is a proper 1-dimensional $k$ scheme?

Thank you

Comment: What kind of quotient do you intend here? Categorical? Geometric? What sort of universal property is the morphism $X\to X/G$ supposed to have?

Comment: The quotient in the cathegory of schemes as described in the exercises of the Liu's book